# Solr. When exactly is reindexing necessary. Is it only after a change in your schema.xml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

After getting errors on heroku, reindexing solved the problem. When do I need to reindex my solr database, besides after there is a change in schema.xml (couldn't find it clearly defined in the documentation). Does a change in schema.rb result in needing to reindex again? I would appreciate answers to avoid running into problems in production.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot?

Comment: I have the gems  gem 'sunspot_solr'

Comment: gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 1.3.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reindex each time you change how data is stored.
As you are using sunspot gem, there are two main places you could change how data is stored:

1- schema.xml as you mentioned

2- Searchable blocks that looks similar like below

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :body
    text :comments do
      comments.map { |comment| comment.body }
    end
  end
end
```